Problem when I try export '.svg' file in Transitions library in python
I just try a simple example from this source to learn library  :
from transitions.extensions import GraphMachine
from functools import partial


class Model:

    def clear_state(self, deep=False, force=False):
        print("Clearing state ...")
        return True


model = Model()
machine = GraphMachine(model=model, states=['A', 'B', 'C'],
                       transitions=[
                           {'trigger': 'clear', 'source': 'B', 'dest': 'A', 'conditions': model.clear_state},
                           {'trigger': 'clear', 'source': 'C', 'dest': 'A',
                            'conditions': partial(model.clear_state, False, force=True)},
                       ],
                       initial='A', show_conditions=True)

model.get_graph().draw('my_state_diagram.svg', prog='dot')

but when I run it - without any error - my_state_diagram.svg contains :
---
State Machine
---
stateDiagram-v2
  direction LR
  classDef s_default fill:white,color:black
  classDef s_inactive fill:white,color:black
  classDef s_parallel color:black,fill:white
  classDef s_active color:red,fill:darksalmon
  classDef s_previous color:blue,fill:azure
  
  state "A" as A
  Class A s_active
  state "B" as B
  Class B s_default
  state "C" as C
  Class C s_default
  
  B --> A: clear [clear_state]
  C --> A: clear [clear_state(False, force=True)]
  [*] --> A

how can I fix this?
and my second question : how can I export .dot file?

What leads you to believe that the transitions library should be able to output SVG?

The README states:

Transitions can generate basic state diagrams displaying all valid transitions between states. The basic diagram support generates a mermaid state machine definition which can be used with mermaid's live editor, in markdown files in GitLab or GitHub and other web services. [...] To use more sophisticated graphing functionality, you'll need to have graphviz and/or pygraphviz installed. To generate graphs with the package graphviz, you need to install Graphviz manually or via a package manager.

The mermaid export you see is more or less a fallback since you don't have any Graphviz library installed. So your problem could probable be solved by installing pygraphviz with e.g:
pip install pygraphviz

You can verify the correct backend by having a look at the graph class:
print(machine.graph_cls)
# without pygraphviz
>>> <class 'transitions.extensions.diagrams_mermaid.Graph'>
# with pygraphviz
>>> <class 'transitions.extensions.diagrams_pygraphviz.Graph'>

With pygraphviz installed, transitions will use it since this is the 'traditional' default. Your code should generate an SVG file. Since SO does not support SVGs, here is a screenshot of it in my IDE:


thanks but i got another error while installing pygraphviz : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78985171/problem-installing-pygraphiz-graphviz-cgraph-h-no-such-file-or-directory
